# How can I store list items in string.xml file instead of Java?

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have just started learning recyclerview. In most tutorials I saw they store the array list in the Java. I want to know how can I bring out resources kept in string.xml to the java .

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in String.xml and use this String of Array..

```xml
    <array name="arrayName">
                <item>item 1</item>
                <item>item 2</item>
    </array>
```

Comment: I've done already but I can't take it to the main java and show in recyclerview

Comment: getString(R.string.arrayName) you can use it like this

Answer (score 0):

In short, this is how you define a static string array in an Android XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="my_books">
        <item>Scala Cookbook</item>
        <item>Play Framework Recipes</item>
        <item>How I Sold My Business: A Personal Diary</item>
        <item>A Survival Guide for New Consultants</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then inside an Activity, Fragment, or other Java class, you can create a string array in Java from that XML like this:

```java
Resources res = getResources();
String[] myBooks = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_books);
```